# caption not centered for subfigure

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats, subcaption

I have three plots which I want to display one after the other. It displays fine but the only problem I have is the captions are not centered. the  subcaptions are more obvious after rendering the picture below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}

   \hspace*{-1.1in}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption{\small a image }    
        \label{fig:subfigure1}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \hspace*{-1.1in}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}  
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small b image}}    
        \label{fig:subfigure2}
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \hspace*{-1.1in}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}   
        \centering 
        \includegraphics[scale=0.37]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption[]%
        {{\small c image}}    
        \label{fig:subfigure3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption[ whole image caption here]
    {\small whole image caption here} 
    \label{fig:experiments}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

I am adding the image because it is extra wide, it is what I am using as a test

[image: dummy.jpg]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wjJ6.jpg

Comment: You probably want something like `width=\linewidth` rather than `scale`. If you want to increase the text block width temporarily, use something like `changepage`. And then look at the configuration options for configuring sub-captions and captions e.g. font size, alignment etc.

Answer (score 1):

As @cfr has already pointed out in a comment, you should replace the three `[scale=0.37]` options with `[width=\textwidth]`. Omit the three redundant `\centering` instructions and replace both instances of `\vskip\baselineskip\hspace*{-1.1in}` with `\vspace{1\baselineskip}`.  Finally, run the instruction `\captionsetup{font=small}` to save yourself from having to insert `\small` in the body of each and every `\caption` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % omit 'demo' option in real document

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
\captionsetup{font=small} % font size for caption and subcaptions
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption{a image }    
        \label{fig:subfigure1}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}  
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption{b image}  
        \label{fig:subfigure2}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{\textwidth}   
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{dummy.jpg}
        \caption{c image}
        \label{fig:subfigure3}
    \end{subfigure}

    \caption[whole image caption here]{whole image caption here} 
    \label{fig:experiments}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. The plots are nicely arranged and with centered captions now but I would like to be able to stretch the image so as to spill in the margins on both sides. Making it larger than `width=\textwidth`  and start it from somewhere in the left margin space . This is why I thought `\hspace*{-1.1in}` would work, but seems to be dragging the captions with it.